# How to work with classes/objects in php

Tags: php, class, oop

I am having difficult time understanding classes, I'm a bit lost on how i setup mine which is supposed to store information of my database so I can call upon it when i need it.

My class looks like this:

```
class db
{
    function data()
    {
        $t = new stdClass;
        $t->users = new stdClass;
        $t->users->table = 'user_table';
        $t->users->userid = 'userid';
    }
}


$db = new db();
$data = $db->data;

echo $data->users->table;
```

Unfortunately I am getting:

```
Undefined property: db::$data
```

Where have I gone wrong, I seem to struggle to understand classes.

Comment: `data` is a method in your case, but you're trying to access it as a property. Did you mean `$data = $db->data()`?

Comment: Also you probably wanted to `return $t`.

Comment: Try changing $data to a different variable name like $varData so there is no conflict with data() function, also The line that says `$data = $db->data;` change to `$data = $db->data();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to access `data` as a property but it is a method in your class. What you want is something like this:

```
<?php
class db
{
    public $data;
    function data()
    {       
     $this->data->users                  =  new stdClass;
     $this->data->users->table           = 'user_table';
     $this->data->users->userid          = 'userid';
    }

}
?>
```

That would allow you to do the following:

```
<?php
    $db = new db();
    $db->data();

    echo $db->data->users->table;
?>
```

---

**Foot Notes**
You'd probably be better setting the config as an array:

```
function data(){
    $this->data = array(
        'table' => 'user_table',
        'userid' => 'userid',
    );
}
```

Which would allow you to access it like the following below:

```
$db = new db();
$db->data();
print_r($db->data);
```

Returning:

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [table] => user_table
            [userid] => userid
        )

)
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/168317)

Which allows access like this:

```
echo $db->data['users']['table'];
```

Comment: For some reason the first example gives: `Trying to get property of non-object` for `$data = $db->data;`

Comment: Ok that fixed that issue but i now get: `Creating default object from empty value` for `$this->data->users = new stdClass;`

Comment: @Dave See next edit (Foot Notes), probably the better alternative for you.

Comment: Okay i'll give it a go, will i need a data function for each individual table then ? Or just expand on the `this->data['']`

Comment: @Dave Could you elaborate on that more please?

Comment: No need i fiddled and worked it out! Thanks for the help it works great now!